# Validate only dirty inputs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My current web project has an administration interface, in which the details of a user can be edited (not really revolutionizing, I admit...). The view uses a strongly typed model of a user, with validation attributes:

```
public class UserPrototype
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 4)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(250, MinimumLength = 6]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    /*
      And so on
    */
}
```

When the user is updated, I would like to only update in the database those fields that have actually changed. The main reason is the password field - the password is of course stored as a hash, so when the user is retieved for editing there is nothing meaningful to display in that field. But the model binder validation requires a valid password.

So, can I still use the same class, but somehow only validate those fields that are submitted as changed (this I can accomplish though javascript)? I would like to avoid duplicating the `UserPrototype` class just to remove the `Required` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use inheritance, this way you don't have to duplicate.

```
public class BaseUserPrototype
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 4)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    /*
      And so on
    */
}

public class NewUserPrototype: BaseUserPrototype
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250, MinimumLength = 6]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    /*
      And so on
    */
}
public class EditUserPrototype: BaseUserPrototype
{
    [StringLength(250, MinimumLength = 6]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    /*
      And so on
    */
}
```

Comment: Ah, but I still want it to be *possible* to change the password. But not having to know the password and reenter it just to change some other parameter...

Comment: Updated my answer. In the edit scenario remove the required attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IDataErrorInfo interface;
Implement it on your entity this way:

```
public class Entity: IDataErrorInfo
{
// this is the dictionary of errors
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private string _password;

    public string Password
    {
        get{return _password;}
        set
        {
        // YOUR ACTUAL VALIDATION CODE HERE. IF THERE IS A VALIDATION ERROR - ADD IT TO THE DICTIONARY
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            _errors["Password"] = "Error with password field";
        }
    }
}
```